# Priority Queues - Array based implementation

Tags: c++, oop

I am learning about stacks, queues, lists & hash tables from the book *Data Structures using C and C++ by Tenenbaum*. I am also spending time to take in OOPs essentials, to ensure they sink in well, so that I don't learn by osmosis/need-be basis in the future, and there are no knowledge gaps.

The author of the book suggests, that an array based implementation of the ascending & descending priority queues can be realized using circular, ordered arrays. The author leaves the implementation of the routines `insert()` and `remove()`, as an exercise to the reader.

I built a PriorityQueue class. My implementation of insert() and remove() routines is very cryptic. I produce the code verbatim for completeness(and not spamming). Could my implementation be better, readable and is it object oriented?

Your tips would be of immense help.

```
#ifndef PQueue_H
#define PQueue_H

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

const int maxsize = 5;

template <class T>
class PQueue
{
    T items[maxsize];
    int front, rear,n;

public:
    PQueue(T val);
    PQueue(const PQueue<T>& q);
    ~PQueue();
    void insert(T x, int& overflow);
    int search_position(T x);
    T remove(int& underflow);
    T first(int& underflow) const;
    T last(int& underflow) const;
    int size() const;
    bool empty() const;
    void print () const;
    void increment(int& i);
    void decrement(int& i);
};

template <class T>
PQueue<T>::PQueue(T val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxsize; i++)
        items[i] = val;

    front = rear = maxsize - 1;
    n = 0;
}

template <class T>
PQueue<T>::PQueue(const PQueue<T>& q)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < q.n; i++)
    {
        items[i] = q.items[i];
    }
    front = rear = maxsize - 1;
    n = 0;
}

template <class T>
PQueue<T>::~PQueue() {};

template <class T>
int PQueue<T>::search_position(T x)
{
    int low = front, high = rear;
    int i;

    if (empty()) {
        return (rear+1)%maxsize;
    }


    for (i = (front+1)%maxsize; i != (rear+1)%maxsize; increment(i))
    {   
        if (items[i] > x)
            break;
    }
    return i;
}

template <class T>
void PQueue<T>::insert(T x, int& overflow)
{
    overflow = 0;
    if ((rear + 1) % maxsize == front)
    {
        overflow = 1;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int index = search_position(x);
        std::cout << "\nInserting item " << x << " at position " << index;

        increment(rear);

        //If index matches the updated value of rear,
        //there must be nothing to shift.
        if(index!=rear)
        {
            int i = rear - 1, j = rear;
            i += maxsize; i %= maxsize;
            j += maxsize; j %= maxsize;

            do
            {
                //Shift all elements 1 position to 
                //the right in item[index...rear]
                items[j] = items[i];
                std::cout << "\nShifting item " << items[i] << " from index "
                    << i << " to " << j;
                decrement(i); 
                decrement(j);

            } while (j != index);
        }
        n++;
        items[index] = x;
    }
}

template <class T>
T PQueue<T>::remove(int& underflow)
{
    underflow = 0;
    if (empty())
    {
        underflow = 1;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        increment(front);

        std::cout << "\nRemoving item " << items[front] << " from the front";
        n--;
        return items[front];
    }
}

template <class T>
T PQueue<T>::first(int& underflow) const
{
    if (empty())
    {
        underflow = 1;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return items[(front + 1) % maxsize];
    }
}

template <class T>
T PQueue<T>::last(int& underflow) const
{
    if (empty())
    {
        underflow = 1;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return items[rear];
    }
}

template <class T>
int PQueue<T>::size() const
{
    return n;
}

template <class T>
bool PQueue<T>::empty() const
{
    if (front == rear)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template <class T>
void PQueue<T>::print() const
{
    std::cout << "\nQueue items : ";
    for (int i = (front + 1) % maxsize; i != (rear+1)%maxsize; i=(++i)%maxsize)
    {
        std::cout << "items[" << i << "] = " << items[i] << "\t";
    }
}

template <class T>
void PQueue<T>::increment(int& i)
{
    ++i;
    i %= maxsize;
}

template <class T>
void PQueue<T>::decrement(int& i)
{
    --i;
    i += maxsize; i %= maxsize;
}


#endif // !PriorityQueue_H
```

Thanks,

Quasar.

Comment: If there are no problems in your code and you just want to review it, you should better post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I am kinda new to both StackOverflow and CodeReview, so I wasn't entirely sure where to post this. Thanks for suggesting it - let me do that.

Comment: Basically, SO is about finding errors/bugs and CR is about reviewing working code and making it better.